# Implement a macro in superclass and expand it in subclasses

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I want to do something like this:

```
trait Endo {
  def apply[T](x: T): T
}

trait SuperType {
  def endoMap(f: Endo): SuperType = macro SuperTypeMacro.endoMapImpl
}

case class Foo(x: Int) extends SuperType {
  // endoMapImpl expands to
  // Foo(f(x))
}

case class Bar(x: Int, y: Boolean) extends SuperType {
  // endoMapImpl expands to
  // Bar(f(x), f(y))
}
```

Ideally the only thing I would need to write is `extends SuperType`. Is it possible? If not, I believe macro annotations should allow this; am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `c.prefix`, that contains the receiver of the current macro method call. Once you get hold of it, you can branch on its type.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure it's enough. I only have the static type of the receiver from `c.prefix`, right? If I can enumerate all subtypes of `SuperType`, it's fine, but if someone else extends `SuperType` without recompiling it, I have problems.

Comment: Yes, only the static type. You can also store the information that would help the macro branch in derived classes - in annotations, in signatures of methods, etc. If you could provide a full use case, I might be able to tell more.